# Creating a FAT file system and save it into a file in GNU/linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, vfat

I tell you my problem:
I want to create a FAT file system and save it into a file so I can mount it in linux using something like:

```
sudo mount -t msdos <file> <dest_folder>
```

Maybe I'm wrong and this cannot be done.

Anyway, the problem is this:
I'm trying to create the file containing a FAT file system, and I'm running this command:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat  -F 32 -r 112 -S 512 -v -C "test.fat" 100
```

That, accordingly to the mkfs man page, will create a FAT32 file system with 112 rootdir entries, logical sector size of 512 bytes, 100 blocks in total, and save it into "test.fat".

But it fails, and the bash tells me:

```
mkfs.vfat: unable to create test.fat
```

What is going on? I think I am misunderstanding how mkfs works and how to use it.
It is possible to write a filesystem into a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a file of 0 bytes in size. You can only create a filesystem on a file that has a specified size.

Here is how to do it properly:

1. `dd if=/dev/zero of=fat.fs bs=1024 count=SIZE` how big do you want the filesystem; specify it as `SIZE * 1024`.
2. `mkfs.vfat fat.fs` formats the file as the filesystem FAT.
3. `mount -o loop  fat.fs /mnt` mounts fat.fs to `/mnt`.

Comment: If you are doing some sort of automated build then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798605/1127972) might be useful too.